# Почему нельзя возвести отрицательное число в вещественную степень?

Tags: c#, .net, математика

Почему Math.Pow(-120, 0.1) = NaN?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Потому что корень для отрицательных чисел извлекается только для непарных степеней. А 0.1 - это 1/10, то-есть корень десятой степени. Имеется ввиду, что нет такого вещественного числа, которое в 10 степени дало бы -120.

Comment: а как получить в коде для -120^0.1 = -1.6

Просто Microsoft Mathematics решила это как-то и выдала мне именно -1.6.

Comment: а там точно -120^0.1 = -1.6, а не -(120^0.1) = -1.6?

Comment: http://imagepost.ru/images/r/of/rofzkbprvldyymiipvhbuqjiggslkj.png

http://s51.radikal.ru/i131/1208/ee/94b8ed4f01de.png

Comment: Не могу пройти по ссылке, "403 Forbidden"

Comment: Да, видишь, оно восприняло -120^0.1 как -(120^0.1). Если хочешь, чтобы твоя программа также посчитала, то поменяй Math.Pow(-120, 0.1) на -Math.Pow(120, 0.1).

Answer (score 7):

Потому что надо было учить математику в школе.

Возведение отрицательного числа в нецелую степень в общем случае имеет результатом комплексное число, то есть число с мнимой частью.

```
i=sqrt(-1); //определение мнимого числа
```

Надо использовать спец. библиотеку с поддержкой комплексной математики, [например](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/complex.h/cpow)